# CSS changes when logging out Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a simple image gallery, and I suddenly noticed
a weird bug I can't figure out.

The page looks the way its supposed to when a user is logged in, however
once the user logs out, the image-specific CSS gets destroyed.

I'm using Rails 4 with Twitter Bootstrap gem

ERB/HTML

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 prosjekt_ramme">
      <div class="prosjekt">
        <p class="prosjekt_content">
          <%= project.content %>
           <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <%= link_to 'Slett', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Er du sikker?' } %> </p>                               
           <% end %>
          <%= image_tag(project.picture.url, class: "img-responsive project_image") %>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
   <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.prosjekt {
 background-color: #eee;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 height: 350px;

 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  }
}
```

If I remove

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
          <%= link_to 'Slett', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Er du sikker?' } %></p>                               
<% end %>
```

The image-specific CSS stays destroyed, whether I'm logged in or not.
Got any idea what's going on?

Comment: It might have something to do with the trailing p closing tag :`</p>`.  Since the closing tag is within the if statement, it only closes on that condition. Try moving it after the `<% end %>`

Comment: Aww, you are completely right!. Thank you so much, sometimes it helps letting someone else look at your code! :-)

Comment: Great!  I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing your `p` tag within the `if` conditional.  As a result, it never closes if the user is not signed in.  This is probably what is messing up the styling.  Try this:

```
<div class="prosjekt">
    <p class="prosjekt_content">
        <%= project.content %>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
           <%= link_to 'Slett', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Er du sikker?' } %>                              
        <% end %>
    </p>
    <%= image_tag(project.picture.url, class: "img-responsive project_image") %>
</div>
```

Or, if you don't want the link to be part of the paragraph:

```
<div class="prosjekt">
    <p class="prosjekt_content">
        <%= project.content %>
    </p>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to 'Slett', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Er du sikker?' } %>                              
    <% end %>
    <%= image_tag(project.picture.url, class: "img-responsive project_image") %>
</div>
```